# Sending messages to my bot via Slack gets no response

Tags: botframework

I have a bot deployed to our Azure subscription. Using the webchat channel, I can interact with the bot using the url:

`http://mybotname.azurewebsites.net/`

We have added the bot to Slack as an app. We followed all the instructions given by the documentation on how to add a bot into Slack - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

When I send a message to the bot in the Slack channel we have created, I get no response. There is not error message, or in fact anything, returned.

[image]

Whereabouts can I start looking to see what the problem could be? Suggestions for error logs, traces, etc would be appreciated. I enabled `App insights` for the Azure Web App which the bot runs under, but nothing comes up as an error, or warning, or anything. I'm a bit lost here, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Note that I was made aware that, for Slack, I may need to tailor the responses in order for Slack to render them e.g. [FormFlow define options for string field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817654/formflow-define-options-for-string-field/50477910#50477910)

I'm not sure how to do that, or even if this is a case that my bot simply isn't working in Slack regardless of how I'd format the responses.

Comment: The basic steps to debug that would be: to double-check Slack setup / to redeploy your bot with a basic "echo" function to ensure that the link is fine

Comment: Yeah I'm going to need to "check the plug" on this i.e. Slack settings. I'll change the bot to output a simple bit of text, rather then the formflow dialog, just to prove it can actually return anything.

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest approach to limit side effects!

Comment: Have you tried debugging with [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) yet? To see if there is any information you can gain this way?

Comment: Ah OK. Let me give that a shot. I'm on a short work day today, so it might not be until next week that I can try ngrok. I didn't know you could use it to debug other channels, that sounds awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Any luck with this @Jason?

Comment: I haven't tried it just yet, only because I've been side-tracked with a task to deploy the bot to Facebook, just to test. I will give this a go, though I might encounter some hassle with our network proxy stopping that traffic coming to my PC. I can speak with the network team if that happens, see what they say.

Comment: Yes, that will be an issue.  I highly recommend using Fiddler or something similar to see all the URLs that will need to be whitelisted.